# Why my setTiomeout() fuction doesn't works on loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm new in this thing and I don't understand why is happening.
According to internet setTimeout function is supposed to run my code after
the milliseconds that I choose, and it works, but why when I put it inside
a for loop it just wait for once?
How can I solve it?
tnks

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    },1000)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because setTimeout method is asynchrone.

Comment: "_when I put it inside a for loop it just wait for once_" - It waits for all three. You schedule three timeouts, all of which run after one second. But the scheduling happens simultaneously.